# Simple if...else statement does not work

Tags: if-statement

My simple if...else statement below results in the true condition! I have simplified this from a project I am working on just to see if I would get the same illogical result that I was getting in my project. And I used a fresh spreadsheet and script. What is going on here? I am totally baffled! It's a trivial function just to prove my point. The toast pops up with "aNumber is 7" even though I have defined it with a value of 5 few line above!

Any explanation? I have been searching but cannot find this problem online. Hope you can enlighten me.

```
function testFunction(ss) {

    var aNumber = 5


    if (aNumber = 7){
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("aNumber is 7")
    }else{
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('aNumber IS NOT 7')
    }

}
```

Comment: What language? JavaScript?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Try `if (aNumber == 7)`

Comment: The one problem you may have is that you're using a = and not == on the aNumber == 7

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something wrong in my code due to typo 

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is Javascript You are assigning 7 to aNumber, the comparison operator is '==', like most C-style languages.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **==** to check for IF conditions (in case of Javascript)

```
if (aNumber == 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and similar languages `aNumber = 7` is an assignment returning `7` and `7` is interpreted as `true` (only `0` is `false`).

Use `aNumber == 7` for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Use = when setting the value for a variable.
Use == when comparing two values.

Try this:

function testFunction(ss) {

```
var aNumber = 5


if (aNumber == 7){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("aNumber is 7")
}else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('aNumber IS NOT 7')
}
```

}